# How to get a result with relations but not all the relations

Tags: php, laravel

I need to have an order (table order) that has "hasMany" relation to item.
I need to only get the order that has a certain date on one of its item and only the concerned items.

For example, if I have an order : Order 1 that has 2 items, one that is created the first january and the other in december and I search with the first january, i want to get the order and the item.

```
$order = Order::with('items')->whereHas(
  'items', function ($query) use ($dateFrom, $dateTo) {
    return $query->whereBetween('date_debut', [$dateFrom->format('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00', $dateTo->format('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00'])
      ->with([
        'titles.title',
      ]);
  })->get();
```

With that code, I always get all the items of the order and not only the one I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with inside whereHas has no effects.

you should apply your condition on the [eager load relation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) itself:

```
$orders = Order::with(['items'=>function($query) use ($dateFrom, $dateTo){
            return $query->whereBetween('date_debut', [$dateFrom->format('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00', $dateTo->format('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00'])
                ->with(['titles.title']);
        }])->whereHas(
            'items', function ($query) use ($dateFrom, $dateTo) {
            $query->whereBetween('date_debut', [$dateFrom->format('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00', $dateTo->format('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00']);
        })->get();
```

note if you want all the orders regardless if they has items `wherebetween`, you can remove the `whereHas` statements.